# pandas groupby function is returning only null values as output

Tags: python, pandas, null, pandas-groupby

```
maindata['avg_delay']= maindata.groupby('name_customer')['Delay'].mean(numeric_only=False) 
maindata.avg_delay
```

---

```
output:
0       NaT
1       NaT
2       NaT
4       NaT
5       NaT
         ..
49994   NaT
49996   NaT
49997   NaT
49998   NaT
49999   NaT
Name: avg_delay, Length: 40000, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Edit the question to show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maindata.groupby('name_customer')['Delay'].mean(numeric_only=False)`  gives you a `pd.Series` with values of `'name_customer'` as the Series's indices. Note that when you assign a `pd.Series` to a column of a dataframe, the assignment is index-by-index. Because your `maindata`'s indices is not values from  `'name_customer'`, the two sets of indices do not match with each other, and thus the result you observed.

As the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) says, `transform`:

> Call function producing a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and return a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values

so you may use the following line instead, but do check if the outcome is what you need or not.

```
maindata.groupby('name_customer')['Delay'].transform('mean')
```